# I try to get data from The Movie db API but this error appear:{status_code: 7, status_message: 'Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key.'

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, themoviedb-api

Below is my code:

```
fetch(` https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=<<api_key=${process.env.local}>>&language=en-US&page=1&include_adult=fals&query=${e.target.value}`)
.then((res)=> res.json())
.then(data =>{
    console.log(data)
})
```

and I get below response

> {status_code: 7, status_message: 'Invalid API key: You must be granted a valid key.', success: false}

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer ı guess. Make sure you restart the node.

Just close all the terminals and open another one, then type npm start.

API will start to work with no problem.